# How do I solve WhatsApp sharing issue in C# view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, whatsapp, nopcommerce

I want to share dynamic messages to WhatsApp in nopcommerce Web (C#). I used `whatsapp://send?text=dynamictext` embedded in `<a>`

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=@item.MassageText&utm_source=affiliates&utm_medium=whatsapp&utm_campaign=@campaignParameter" style="line-height:1;border-radius:5px;" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
```

This message `@item.MassageText` display in link, but when click on this link, error encountered in console

> Failed to launch 'whatsapp://send?text=@item.MassageText&utm_source=affiliates&utm_medium=whatsapp&utm_campaign=@campaignParameter'  because the scheme does not have a registered handler

I trying with another way `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=dynamictext`, not any error occurs. When I click on link, it opens WhatsApp application but message not shared.

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=@item.MassageText&utm_source=affiliates&utm_medium=whatsapp&utm_campaign=@campaignParameter" style="line-height:1;border-radius:5px;" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="">
```